# Sending Character or String instead of ASCII code with Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, arduino, bluetooth, outputstream

I am writing an app to send a string of characters to an Arduino using HC-05 bluetooth module.

my problem is I am only able to send it as ascii bytes for example this is my sending method:

```
    private void sendData()
{
    if (!(btOutputStream == null)){
        try {
            btOutputStream.write("Hello".getBytes());
                ToastMaker("Data is sent");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the output of Arduino's serial monitor:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/88l5w.png

and this is the code of Arduino:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial Bluetooth(10, 9); // RX, TX
int Data; // the data received

void setup() {
  Bluetooth.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Waiting for command...");
}

void loop() {
  if (Bluetooth.available()){ //wait for data received
    Data=Bluetooth.read();
    Bluetooth.println(Data);
    Serial.println(Data);
  }
delay(100);
}
```

In conclusion I am looking for a way to get received data(for example for Hello) like this:
H
e
l
l
o

instead of this:
72
101
108
108
111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the ascii code to a character using the `char()` method on the Arduino:

```
char character;

...

character = char(Data);
```

See [the documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/conversion/charcast/) for more information.

Comment: thanks for answer. but for some reason i prefer to do this in android side and only want to do this on microcontroller side if there is not a possible way to do this in android.

Comment: after searching hours i find out that the best way is your way and i must convert ascii code on the micro side.